# OTC Markets, Time, and Trading

Tags: investing

Details: USA Investor, brokerage switched hands

With a past brokerage firm of mine, I purchased shares of RWE AG (a German energy company) and they purchased the shares through the OTC markets ([see here](https://www.google.com/finance?q=OTCMKTS%3aRWNFF&ei=JJztUYCFKJ2KlwOXbA) or [here too](http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RWNFF/quote)).  I've noticed that the date currently and the previous closed date on the symbol (see the Google Finance link) show a large difference.  Does the OTC market work differently when it comes to the trading timeframe (note that this is my first OTC trade, as some brokerages will claim they offer international trading, but what they really mean is that you can buy the symbols in the OTC market not directly on the foreign exchange)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your broker, you can buy these stocks directly at the most liquid local exchanges. For instance, if you are US resident and want to to buy German stocks (like RWE) you can trade these stocks over InteractiveBrokers (or other direct brokers in the US). They offer direct access to German Xetra and other local markets.

Answer (score 2):

Something to consider is that in the case of the company you chose, on the OTC market, that stock is thinly traded and with such low volume, it can be easy for it to fluctuate greatly to have trades occur.  This is why volume can matter for some people when it comes to buying shares.

Some OTC stocks may have really low volume and thus may have bigger swings than other stocks that have higher volume.